# Are Tor server IPs recently blocked to access China Network?

Tags: browsers

In the recent weeks, I (from outside China) try to use tor to browse http websites (esp those major public ones) hosted in China. But it turns out that the browser is always "waiting for xxx.xxx.com ..." and never gets any response. Meanwhile, there is totally no problem to browse websites outside China. It happened back to the end of August 2016. It looks like the GFW of China has blocked Tor servers IPs to access websites inside it.

Can anyone confirm or comment on this? Or it is just I miss to set some (new) configuration?

Comment: post your desired URL's so I'll be able to check

Comment: A simple url for try should be  http://1212.ip138.com/ic.asp 
(extracted from www.ip138.com, it returns your exit IP). 

A more complecated website for try can be http://www.163.com, which is one of the most
popular News websites in China. The webpage usually ends up with partially loaded --
I think the company pobably has some of its servers located outside the China GFW.

Besides, like login of China's most popular IM account from http://aq.qq.com , etc...

Comment: I just tried a few exitnodes, FP:  EF27BB320827F8C809CA999E07B9B783C7ACC8F1, C514A3E6D98385E47BA6D67C632383A549C1C115, DA073774D62BDD9141548C67D7CC2019ED0825AF. All look blocked.


However, you can also find some exception exitnodes, e.g., FP: b6718125c43eca2e5011b3c681bb6638617a9686, whose actual exit IP is not listed anywhere.

So I suspect that they block the TOR network simply according to the listed IPs.

Comment: blocked for me too